# Selenium WebDriver(Java) : JavascriptExecutor fails to click element, while WebElement.click() works well

Tags: java, javascript, selenium

As the following code shows, clicking the element by the WebElement.click() method works, while JavascriptExecutor.executeScript fails ( works in most situaitons ).

```
WebElement e = driver.findElement(By.xpath("......."));//some kind of checkbox
e.click(); //works fine.
((JavascriptExecutor) aw.driver).executeScript("arguments[0].click();",e); 
//executes with no exception, but the element is not selected.
```

The page's source code is too complex to paste here, sorry. 
**Any clue or tip for debugging this  problem?**

The element's html code, It's a extjs-style checkbox:
`<td class="x-grid3-hd x-grid3-cell x-grid3-td-checker x-grid3-cell-first " style="width: 20px;">
<div class="x-grid3-hd-inner x-grid3-hd-checker" id="ext-gen108" unselectable="on" _nodup="30805">
<div class="x-grid3-hd-checker" _nodup="30805" />
</div></td>`

I have tried click each of `td`, `td/div` , `td/div/div` elements , getting same result: `WebElement.click()` works,  `JavascriptExecutor.executeScript` fails(No exception, but the checkbox is not checked).

Answer (score 1):

I would not assume the JavaScriptExecutor failed to execute your Script first, but see if the Script is working as expected.

Try to set break point at "e.click();" and then start debugging, after that try to run your Script (which is "arguments[0].click();" in your case) in browser console and see what happened.

If you have confirmed the script is good, then try to put break point at your executeScript and make sure that line of code have been run successfully.

Answer (score 0):

Instead use 
    document.evaluate()
for JavaScript executor method.something like this:
    executeScript("document.evaluate( \"" ,document, null, XPathResult.FIRST_ORDERED_NODE_TYPE, null ).singleNodeValue.click()");

Comment: It seems that IE doesn't support document.evaluate.